# How can I make a page only accessible if the user comes from a specific site and only that site

Tags: wordpress, web, redirect

Hi so I am an absolute novice in web development. I just know a little bit of Wordpress with no coding knowledge. Anyways to simplify my question I will give an example, say there is a website that sells cars and it has the 
following pages

www.site1.com/honda

www.site1.com/toyota

www.site1.com/bmw

So I have access to these pages and I would like to place a button on these pages that links to my site (www.site2.com/cars). So if anyone from those 3 pages clicks on the button they will come to www.site2.com/cars. Now the tricky part is I don't want this page to be accessible to any other people. So if someone were to type in site2.com/cars it should not load or redirect to another page or something. I would like this to be secure like I don't want someone to spoof there way into www.site2.com/cars but at the moment if that is too complicated to achieve I am ok with it.

I have looked into this on this websites and I have found some similar questions or even identical ones but I did not understand them.
Please let me know if this is possible and how I can achieve this thanks very much in advance.

Comment: have u considered having people register on to your site and then give them permissions to specific pages.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option  for me. Trust me if it was I would have done it in a heartbeat.

Answer (score 2):

If the website that links to your website is not yours and you cannot modify it, the only thing that you can do is check in the headers of the incoming request. There is a referer key that has the URL of the website the user has come from.

Comment: I upvoted this answer as it's probably the easiest to do if you're concerned about security. the referer can be spoofed.

Comment: Ok so sounds like this is the option for me so can you give me an idea of what I need to do or like link a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is by enabling authentication on these sites. A user logs into any of these sites, get a session token and only those with this session token can access your site

Comment: Yeah this is a great idea but unfortunately it's not an option for this particularly situation.